# How can we set abbreviations in Lua for Neovim?

Tags: neovim, lua, init.lua

I am using Neovim and I asked this question from Google Bard and it was answered with this code:

```lua
vim.g.abbreviations = {
  ["btw"] = "by the way",
  ["imo"] = "in my opinion",
  ["func"] = function()
    vim.insert("def ${1}(...):\n  ${2}\nend")
  end,
}
```

I copied this code into my init.lua but it does not work.  I searched in the Neovim doc but I could not find anything like this. Do we have something like this in Neovim? I want to set some abbreviations in my config, how can I do that?

Comment: Frankly, don’t trust the LLMs for expert advice. Try the documentation and ask questions :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I just want to know how can I define a list of abbreviations in Lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there are no specific Lua API for that.
You can do:

```lua
vim.cmd('abbreviate jhon john')
```